# Hex Conversion to Decimal

Tags: hex, decimal

I don't understand why big endian [00 02 B1 10] makes decimal [176,400].

The way I convert it is to convert each hex pair of digits to decimal and multiply it by 16 to the 'correct' power:

00 * 16^3 = **0**

02 * 16^2 = **512**

B1 * 16^1 = **192**

10 * 16^0 = **16**

**0 + 512 + 192 + 16 = 720**

But this can't be right. What is the correct method for converting the big endian hex value [00 02 B1 10] to decimal [176,400]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert each hex digit individually, not as a pair:

```
 2 * 16^4 = 131072
11 * 16^3 = 45056   // B = decimal 11
 1 * 16^2 = 256
 1 * 16^1 = 16
 0 * 16^0 = 0

131072 + 45056 + 256 + 16 = 176400
```